# UIActionSheet & Human Interface Guidelines

Tags: ios

I have taken to using the UIActionSheet as a form of delivering critical error messages to the user -- for example, when attempting to save invalid contents I may put up an action sheet with a single button informing the user of the error.

My question is whether this is apt to run afoul of HIG or cause problems with the App Store acceptance?  It isn't over-used, but only on rare occasions where an error message describing the nature of the problem is essential.

Anyone know about this?

TIA

Comment: No one can say for sure what Apple will approve or not. But it is unlikely that using an action sheet to show an error message will cause problems. Though typically a `UIAlertView` is used for such messages.

Answer (score 3):

Irrespective of what Apple decides, why change a user's expectation?  Error messages are usually localized and displayed as part of the 'UIAlertView' 'message' - it is designed to allow for something of an extended message.  A 'UIActionSheet' 'title' is meant to be a title, not a message.

Comment: The main reason for doing this is the alert view has a lousy look to it and I don't want to invest the time in customizing it for minimal use when I can get a decent look out of the stock Action Sheet.  But your point is taken.

Answer (score 2):

Page 168, [official Apple iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/MobileHIG.pdf) states:

> An action sheet displays a set of choices related to a task the user
>   initiates.

You are therefore breaking these guidelines by using an actionsheet to display an error message.